# Button not working in my Android app as expected

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming, and I am trying to send the text from two `editText` field from my android app to raspberry pi using PHP and JSON.
Everything is working fine and the data can be viewed in the database but the only problem is when I click on the SEND button in my app it does nothing. But when I click anywhere near the SEND button then it sends the data. I used the onClick method from the layout file defined in `activity_main.xml`.
Here is my `MainActivity.java` code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    Button button;
    private View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.partNumber);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    }

    public void Send(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        new Create_Part().execute();
    }

    class Create_Part extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending part to the database...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String String_name = editText.getText().toString();
            String Int_Part = editText2.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", String_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("part_nr", Int_Part));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://192.168.2.1/db_create.php", "POST", params);

            try {
                int success = json.getInt("success");

                if (success == 1) {
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

My `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dipankarroy.rpitoandroidmessengerapp.MainActivity"
    android:onClick="Send"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="@string/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/partNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:hint="@string/part_number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/partNumber"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:onClick="Send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: first remove private View view; this line

Comment: Where is the `onClickListener` for button ?

Comment: suppose onclick property map Send method. Share your activity_main layout

Comment: I've added the activity_main.xml file. I used the `public void Send(View view)` method. Tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a click listener for the button:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then implement `View.OnClickListener` on your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
  @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    new Create_Part().execute();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is showing Method invocation may produce java.lang.NullPointerException warning

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:onClick="Send"` from your root `RelativeLayout`. When you click anywhere else than your button you actually are clicking on your root layout and its calling `Send(View view)` method in your activity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dipankarroy.rpitoandroidmessengerapp.MainActivity"
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can like this -

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {              

               new Create_Part().execute();                 

            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you.